# Simple Automatic Refresh using JavaScript in a Razor Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to know how to do a simple refresh of an HTML table, without re-loading the whole page.

I would like the timer to be set to refresh every 5 seconds.

The Razor code is:

```
<table class="table trim-list search-results" id="res">
    <tbody>

   @foreach (Record record in Model.Results)
   {

       var renditionuri = getRendition(record);                                     

                <tr style="float:left;">                                 
                    <td class="row-icon">
                        <div id="thumb_col" style="margin-right:10%;">
                            <img class="thumbnail" style="padding:3px;" src="~/record/@record.Uri/recordrendition/@renditionuri"/>                        
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="prop-val">   
                        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Title: </label>&thinsp;
                            <a href="~/Record/@record.Uri">@record.Title</a>&thinsp;<br>                            
                        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Record Number:</label>&thinsp;
                            @record.Number<br>
                        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Media Format:</label>&thinsp;
                            @record.GetPropertyOrFieldString("MediaFormat")<br>
                        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Author:</label>&thinsp;
                            @record.GetPropertyOrFieldString("RecordAuthor")<br />
                        <label style="font-weight:bold;">Tags:</label>&thinsp;
                            @record.Notes
                    </td>
                </tr>
       }
   }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if you have tried anything but you could give a look to `setInterval` with javascript and some partial views to reload your table.

1. First you could create a partial view like this: (create a partialview called "_Results" or whatever you want)

   ```
    public ActionResult GetPartialResults()
    {
         Results yourModel = new Results();
         //your logic here to populate your model
         return PartialView("_Results", yourModel);
    }
   ```
2. Then your partial view you put your code:

   ```
   @model YourProject.Models.Results //or whatever your model is
   <table class="table trim-list search-results" id="res">
       <tbody>

       @foreach (Record record in Model.Results)
       {

          var renditionuri = getRendition(record);                                     

               <tr style="float:left;">                                 
                   <td class="row-icon">
                       <div id="thumb_col" style="margin-right:10%;">
                           <img class="thumbnail" style="padding:3px;" src="~/record/@record.Uri/recordrendition/@renditionuri"/>                        
                       </div>
                   </td>
                   <td class="prop-val">   
                       <label style="font-weight:bold;">Title: </label>&thinsp;
                           <a href="~/Record/@record.Uri">@record.Title</a>&thinsp;<br>                            
                       <label style="font-weight:bold;">Record Number:</label>&thinsp;
                           @record.Number<br>
                       <label style="font-weight:bold;">Media Format:</label>&thinsp;
                           @record.GetPropertyOrFieldString("MediaFormat")<br>
                       <label style="font-weight:bold;">Author:</label>&thinsp;
                           @record.GetPropertyOrFieldString("RecordAuthor")<br />
                       <label style="font-weight:bold;">Tags:</label>&thinsp;
                           @record.Notes
                   </td>
               </tr>
           }
        }
      </tbody>
   </table>
   ```
3. Then in your view you could easily create a `RenderAction` to call that partialview

   ```
   <div id="tableResults">
      @{Html.RenderAction("GetPartialResults", "YourController");}
      <!--you could pass parameters if you need them: , new{ param1 = "yourvalue" } after the controller -->
    </div>
   ```
4. Now below that you could create a simple script that execute every 5 seconds with jquery and javascript

   ```
   <script>
   $(function(){
       setInterval(function(){
          //this code will execute after page loads every 5 seconds, you could change on a click event or whatever you need
          var url = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetPartialResuls", "YourController", new { param1 = "-param1" }))";
          //This part is only neccesary if you are using querystring parameters, if not you can ignore it.
          url = url.replace("-param1", yourVariableOrValueHere);
          //your partialview will reload every 5 seconds with the method you are calling in the controller
          $("#tableResults").load(url);
        }, 5000);
    });
   </script>
   ```

And I think that's everything you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: just to point out that setInterval is dangerous. What happen when the request takes more than 5 seconds ? :D setTimeout with recursive call after request complete will be safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SignalR. please find more details [here](http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/)